# UnityEngine.AddressableAssets.InvalidKeyException

Tags: unity, android, addressable

Unity version 2020.3.20f1.

I am getting this error in the console. The game is working fine in Unity but not in the apk. In apk the scene is loading finely but throwing this error and the characters are not coming. I've already build the addressables. Need a solution for this.

```
UnityEngine.AddressableAssets.InvalidKeyException: Exception of type 'UnityEngine.AddressableAssets.InvalidKeyException' was thrown., Key=7a76daf4b39370543abe********, Type=UnityEngine.GameObject
0x00007ff6ec467c1c (Unity) StackWalker::GetCurrentCallstack
0x00007ff6ec4702b9 (Unity) StackWalker::ShowCallstack
0x00007ff6ed9945bc (Unity) GetStacktrace
0x00007ff6eeac56f3 (Unity) DebugStringToFile
0x00007ff6ec53bf56 (Unity) DebugLogHandler_CUSTOM_Internal_Log
0x00000165b674cf7b (Mono JIT Code) (wrapper managed-to-native) UnityEngine.DebugLogHandler:Internal_Log (UnityEngine.LogType,UnityEngine.LogOption,string,UnityEngine.Object)
0x00000165b674cecb (Mono JIT Code) UnityEngine.DebugLogHandler:LogFormat (UnityEngine.LogType,UnityEngine.Object,string,object[])
0x00000165b674cc50 (Mono JIT Code) UnityEngine.Logger:Log (UnityEngine.LogType,object)
0x000001665ebf1b55 (Mono JIT Code) UnityEngine.Debug:LogError (object)
0x000001665ebf170b (Mono JIT Code) [AddressablesImpl.cs:264] UnityEngine.AddressableAssets.AddressablesImpl:LogException (UnityEngine.ResourceManagement.AsyncOperations.AsyncOperationHandle,System.Exception) 
0x000001665ebf1696 (Mono JIT Code) [AsyncOperationBase.cs:309] UnityEngine.ResourceManagement.AsyncOperations.AsyncOperationBase`1<TObject_REF>:set_OperationException (System.Exception) 
0x00000165b677e883 (Mono JIT Code) [AsyncOperationBase.cs:431] UnityEngine.ResourceManagement.AsyncOperations.AsyncOperationBase`1<TObject_REF>:Complete (TObject_REF,bool,System.Exception,bool) 
0x00000165b77f0dbb (Mono JIT Code) [ResourceManager.cs:506] UnityEngine.ResourceManagement.ResourceManager/CompletedOperation`1<TObject_REF>:Execute () 
0x00000165b67643e7 (Mono JIT Code) [AsyncOperationBase.cs:475] UnityEngine.ResourceManagement.AsyncOperations.AsyncOperationBase`1<TObject_REF>:InvokeExecute () 
0x00000165b6763fcb (Mono JIT Code) [AsyncOperationBase.cs:470] UnityEngine.ResourceManagement.AsyncOperations.AsyncOperationBase`1<TObject_REF>:Start (UnityEngine.ResourceManagement.ResourceManager,UnityEngine.ResourceManagement.AsyncOperations.AsyncOperationHandle,DelegateList`1<single>) 
0x00000165b67639db (Mono JIT Code) [ResourceManager.cs:461] UnityEngine.ResourceManagement.ResourceManager:StartOperation<TObject_REF> (UnityEngine.ResourceManagement.AsyncOperations.AsyncOperationBase`1<TObject_REF>,UnityEngine.ResourceManagement.AsyncOperations.AsyncOperationHandle) 
0x00000165b77ef203 (Mono JIT Code) [ResourceManager.cs:602] UnityEngine.ResourceManagement.ResourceManager:CreateCompletedOperationInternal<TObject_REF> (TObject_REF,bool,System.Exception,bool) 
0x000001665ebf130b (Mono JIT Code) [ResourceManager.cs:595] UnityEngine.ResourceManagement.ResourceManager:CreateCompletedOperationWithException<TObject_REF> (TObject_REF,System.Exception) 
0x000001665ebe6d53 (Mono JIT Code) [AddressablesImpl.cs:573] UnityEngine.AddressableAssets.AddressablesImpl:LoadAssetAsync<TObject_REF> (object) 
0x000001665ebe655b (Mono JIT Code) [Addressables.cs:532] UnityEngine.AddressableAssets.Addressables:LoadAssetAsync<TObject_REF> (object) 
0x000001665ebe621b (Mono JIT Code) [AssetReference.cs:503] UnityEngine.AddressableAssets.AssetReference:LoadAssetAsync<TObject_REF> () 
0x00000165b78260a1 (Mono JIT Code) [FishManager.cs:244] Ultramonster.FishManager/<CreateFishPool>d__47:MoveNext () 
0x00000165b674c49c (Mono JIT Code) UnityEngine.SetupCoroutine:InvokeMoveNext (System.Collections.IEnumerator,intptr)
0x00000165b674c5c7 (Mono JIT Code) (wrapper runtime-invoke) <Module>:runtime_invoke_void_object_intptr (object,intptr,intptr,intptr)
0x00007ff96741e660 (mono-2.0-bdwgc) [mini-runtime.c:2827] mono_jit_runtime_invoke 
0x00007ff9673a2ae2 (mono-2.0-bdwgc) [object.c:2921] do_runtime_invoke 
0x00007ff9673abb3f (mono-2.0-bdwgc) [object.c:2968] mono_runtime_invoke 
0x00007ff6ec2ef434 (Unity) scripting_method_invoke
0x00007ff6ec2e7935 (Unity) ScriptingInvocation::Invoke
0x00007ff6ec283b0f (Unity) Coroutine::Run
0x00007ff6ec2805fc (Unity) Coroutine::ContinueCoroutine
0x00007ff6eb754df4 (Unity) DelayedCallManager::Update
0x00007ff6ebbc90b9 (Unity) `InitPlayerLoopCallbacks'::`2'::UpdateScriptRunDelayedDynamicFrameRateRegistrator::Forward
0x00007ff6ebba9a9c (Unity) ExecutePlayerLoop
0x00007ff6ebba9b73 (Unity) ExecutePlayerLoop
0x00007ff6ebbb09a9 (Unity) PlayerLoop
0x00007ff6ed007a21 (Unity) PlayerLoopController::UpdateScene
0x00007ff6ed0056b9 (Unity) Application::TickTimer
0x00007ff6ed99ddb1 (Unity) MainMessageLoop
0x00007ff6ed9a1df1 (Unity) WinMain
0x00007ff6ef7f92b6 (Unity) __scrt_common_main_seh
0x00007ffa1f2254e0 (KERNEL32) BaseThreadInitThunk
0x00007ffa2016485b (ntdll) RtlUserThreadStart
```

Comment: Can you walk us through the steps to create a Minimal Complete Verifiable Example of the problem, starting with a new, empty project?

Comment: There are way too many variables at play here to be able to diagnose your problem with this information. Where is the addressable payload stored? Does it match the location specified in the build settings? Etc.